# Comments bleeding into right column

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, design

Take a look at this post - [Why is $\frac{987654321}{123456789} = 8.0000000729?!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396135/why-is-987654321-123456789-8-0000000729/). This is what I see (on Windows 7, Chrome 31):

[image]

As you can see, all sufficiently long comments are bleeding into the right column, and some of them are being hidden beneath the community ad for DLMF. Presumably, this is somehow being caused by the long, unbroken string of digits in the third visible comment there.

Update: this is still happening on Chrome 34.

Comment: No repro on IE11 and FF on win7 but confirmed on Chrome.

Comment: Can also be reproduced [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: This doesn't happen on Chrome 37 dev. Can somebody with the stable branch of Chrome check if it's still happening?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to give the containing element a fixed width.
E.g. If the available or desired space is 600px, then make the width of the containing element 600px so the content doesn't overlap.